# Using Command Line Arguments To Input Parameters

Tags: c++, command-line, command-line-arguments

So I have a Windows Studio VS File named RectArea that contains the code to a function to find the area of a rectangle. In another Windows Studio VS file named main1, I have my main function like this:

```
  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
  return 0;
  }
```

How do I use command line arguments to be able to print the area of the rectangle in the main file as soon as i compile it?

I read so much stuff about it online. I just still don't understand what I put for the executable and the stuff after it.

My function for the rectangle's area is in the RectArea file. Do I type in C://RectArea?

It's under a lot more folders though.

Comment: http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~lucia/courses/2131-05/labs/Lab3/CommandLineArguments.html

Comment: It still doesn't tell me about what to actually type in in the command line argument section in VS file though. That's what I'm confused about

Answer (score 1):

Ah, you're confused on how to pass the arguments to the program, not how to interpret them.  Those arguments are not command line arguments passed to the Visual Studio build process; they're arguments that can be changed each time you run the program.

An executable written with an entry point like that can't be run properly via double-click like all the others you've written; you have to open cmd.exe and run the program from there, typing the arguments after the program name separated by a space.